# How to loop over values of a certain column in an excel sheet to get the index of a value using java apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am still new to Java trying only to loop over an excel column.

The Excel sheet:

[image]

I want to have in HashMap or Array so that I can compare these dates later on with another column.

My Code is giving me yet a string as you see in the screenshot:

[image]

How can I change this String to a another Data structure to access the "index" of the values. Something like **dates.get(0) --> So 01-Jul-2018**. I would change the time format later.

The Code section:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fsIP);

XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
  Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
  if (row != null) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0); // getColumn(0)
    if (cell != null) {

      System.out.print(cell);

    }
  }
}
```

What would you like to know further from me?

I would be thankful for every help!

Comment: Why not fetch the cell as a java `Date` object instead of formatting it to a string?

Comment: How can I fetch the cell as java date?

Comment: I know that reading the documentation isn't very trendy these days, but what happens if you [give it a try](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue--)?

Comment: This worked I did it already, but I am still not capable of finding a solution of my Problem :(